# Android : Where should a OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener be defined/registered

Tags: android, android-preferences

Design question basically - having a `PreferenceActivity` should one make it implement `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` or should one define this functionality in another class - say in an inner class ? Is there some reason one would prefer the one over the other approach ?

Also where should one register the listener ? I mean [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#ReadingPrefs) and common sense dictate to register/unregister in `onResume/onPause` respectively but having seen [a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2542938/281545) [zillion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13669689/281545) [registrations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10808682/281545) in `onCreate` I just wonder if I am missing something.

Also I am not quite certain if a failure to unregister (so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6105761/281545) for instance unregistering may not be called as `onStop` is not guaranteed to be called) would necessarily lead to a leak. So if I have for instance

```
class MyPref extends PreferenceActivity implements
            OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    // init sharedPreferences
    onStart(){
        sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
    // no unregistration
}
```

Would this leak the `MyPref` instance once I go back to one of my other activities ?

Lastly - would the same considerations apply to `OnPreferenceChangeListener` ?

Edit : coming back to that I see no way to actually unregister the `OnPreferenceChangeListener` - am I blind ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there are any major reasons to favour a particular location for the listener, apart from personal preference. Having the `Activity` implement it, or using an inner class - either anonymous or not - are all OK.

The only thing is, if you're not using an existing object like your `Activity` as the listener, you'll need to keep a reference to the listener object. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3104265/2945062) it will get garbage collected (and thus not actually listen to anything) if you don't.

---

Having dug into the source a bit, it seems `SharedPreferencesImpl` uses a `WeakHashMap` to contain registered listeners ([source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4_r1/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java), lines 72-73, 186-196), meaning that failing to unregister *won't* cause a leak.

As you say, the docs do recommend using `onResume()` / `onPause()`; this is probably nothing to do with leaks, but instead to prevent background apps doing unnecessary processing - so still worth following!

Answer (score 0):

Doing registration and de-registration in `onPause`/`onResume` is lots of extra work for nothing.

You could make an anonymous implementation of your listener as part of your class like this:

```
[class level]
...
OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener mListener = new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener () {
    onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        // your code here
    }
};
...
[class level]
```

Then you set it wherever applicable. If you do this, your listener won't be re-created as a different object between `onPause`/`onResume` (unless your app gets killed and your `Activity` subclass has to be loaded again), so assigning it then is pointless, since you'll always reference the same object. On the other hand, if your app does get killed, then the `onCreate` will be called again.

With regards to implementing an inner class, or not, I tend to prefer having an anonymous implementation (as shown above) due to the enhanced cleanliness of the code - I don't have to bother with class names and have to type fewer brackets. However, it's really a preference thing, so do whatever you feel is better.

Comment: _Doing registration and de-registration_ - why ? wouldn't one need to unregister the listener ? what about the leak I asked ?

Comment: You don't need to unregister it. The system will simply kill it if it decides to kill the app. Besides, each app runs in it's own VM instance, which also gets killed, so you don't have to unregister anything and no leak will happen - all the memory will be released when the process dies (the kernel will take care of that). That is why it's recommended that you save data to persistent storage in `onPause` or `onStop`. However, this doesn't happen between `onPause` and `onResume`.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D, did you find a better answer to this question? If so, why don't you answer it for the benefit of everyone?

Comment: If I had I would have answered don't worry. I am not satisfied yet - unregistering seems to have some purpose or why have the function there ? Sometimes it takes months to answer a question in a satisfying manner - and I do place bounties occasionally

Comment: Sometimes it's better to go dig in the code yourself. If I have the time, I will go deeper in the issue - it's open source after all :)