# Why the receiver defined in manifest is not receiving broadcasts when used with LocalBroadcastManager?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast, localbroadcastmanager

Few days ago I read that there is a better mechanism for sending broadcasts within single application - the `LocalBroadcastManager`.

It works well (just like standard broadcasts..). However, yesterday I've found out that it cannot send broadcasts to receivers, which are defined in the manifest (when I temporarily switched it to use the standard Activity's `sendBroadcast` method, it worked).

The reason why I want this (and correct me if there is a more preferred way to do it) is:

Lets's say I want to download a file. I will use a service, because that's how Android wants us to do. OK, now I want to display (and periodically update) its progress in my activity. So service will be sending broadcasts to my activity and the activity has to register to receive them. The preferred way to handle broadcasts is to register in `onResume()` and unregister in `onPause()`. Now let's imagine that the user is bored with the slowly moving progressbar, so he presses Home and goes to do something else. Later he comes back and wants to see the current status of the download, but how can I tell him, when I unregistered from broadcasts that second he left my application?

That's why I use a receiver defined in the manifest, to be always ready to receive the broadcast and store it permanently (shared preferences, database...), so the activity can reconstruct the latest broadcast when it becomes visible.

However now I'm not sure, whether this routine is not recommended, or why the `LocalBroadcastManager` is not allowing me to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharedPreferences a workaround would be to make your activity implement [`OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html). So the service writes the pref and the activity listens for the change and updates progress bar. `onResume()` you also check the preference and update the UI accordingly.

The nice thing with this is you don't really have a leak if you fail to unregister them - see
[Android : Where should a OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener be defined/registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604536/android-where-should-a-onsharedpreferencechangelistener-be-defined-registered) - I prefer to unregister to `onDestroy()` as I want to have my activity updated even if not in the foreground - and the listener will go away even if `onDestroy` is not called.

As for why it does not work with manifest registered receivers - could you post some code ? Do you actually register the receivers with LBM ?