# On which thread does onReceive() of a BroacastReceiver registered with LocalBroadcastManager run?

Tags: android, multithreading, broadcastreceiver, localbroadcastmanager

I register a broadcast receiver in a preference activity and send it a (sync) broadcast from a (Wakeful) IntentService. Apparently onReceive runs on the service's thread. Is this a fault of my part ? Is it documented behavior ?

Preference activity:

```
public final class SettingsActivity extends BaseSettings {

    private static CharSequence sMasterKey;
    private CheckBoxPreference mMasterPref;
    // Receiver
    /** If the master preference is changed externally this reacts */
    private BroadcastReceiver mExternalChangeReceiver =
        new ExternalChangeReceiver();

    public static void notifyMonitoringStateChange(Context ctx,
            CharSequence action, boolean isToggling) {
        final LocalBroadcastManager lbm = LocalBroadcastManager
            .getInstance(ctx);
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, ExternalChangeReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(action.toString());
        intent.putExtra(TOGGLING_MONITORING_IN_PROGRESS, isToggling);
        lbm.sendBroadcastSync(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        final LocalBroadcastManager lbm = LocalBroadcastManager
            .getInstance(this);
        lbm.registerReceiver(mExternalChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            ac_toggling.toString()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // may not be called in Froyo
        final LocalBroadcastManager lbm = LocalBroadcastManager
            .getInstance(this);
        lbm.unregisterReceiver(mExternalChangeReceiver);
        super.onStop();
    }

    private final class ExternalChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        ExternalChangeReceiver() {}

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("synthetic-access")
        public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
            if (sMasterKey == null || mMasterPref == null) return; // if
            // onPostReceive has not run this will be null
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ac_toggling.equals(action)) {
                final boolean isToggling = intent.getBooleanExtra(
                    TOGGLING_MONITORING_IN_PROGRESS, false);
                Log.w(ExternalChangeReceiver.class.getSimpleName(),
                    "isToggling " + isToggling);
                mMasterPref.setEnabled(!isToggling); // line 168 !!!
                refreshMasterPreference(isToggling);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IntentService (LocationMonitor):

```
SettingsActivity.notifyMonitoringStateChange(this, ac_toggling, true);
```

Exception (E/AndroidRuntime):

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[LocationMonitor]
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:823)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.requestLayout(AbsListView.java:1819)
    at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:813)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:5958)
    at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
    at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
    at android.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter.onPreferenceChange(PreferenceGroupAdapter.java:238)
    at android.preference.Preference.notifyChanged(Preference.java:1099)
    at android.preference.Preference.setEnabled(Preference.java:726)
    at gr.uoa.di.monitoring.android.activities.SettingsActivity$ExternalChangeReceiver.onReceive(SettingsActivity.java:168)
    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcastSync(LocalBroadcastManager.java:278)
    at gr.uoa.di.monitoring.android.activities.SettingsActivity.notifyMonitoringStateChange(SettingsActivity.java:54)
    at gr.uoa.di.monitoring.android.services.Monitor.abort(Monitor.java:241)
    at gr.uoa.di.monitoring.android.services.LocationMonitor.doWakefulWork(LocationMonitor.java:103)
    at com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.WakefulIntentService.onHandleIntent(WakefulIntentService.java:94)
    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

On an emulator API 17

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sendBroadcastSync()` is indeed run on the thread it is called from (except if there is a race going on). Its implementation [should be](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.java):

```
public void sendBroadcastSync(Intent intent) { // directly calls executePendingBroadcasts
        if (sendBroadcast(intent)) {
            executePendingBroadcasts();
        }
}
```

The race part I am not sure about enters via the `sendBroadcast()` call which returns true if it found any matching receiver (registered with LBM for this intent), *after sending a message to a private handler **associated with the main loop*** - abbreviated:

```
@Override
public boolean sendBroadcast(Intent intent) {
    synchronized (mReceivers) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        final ArrayList<ReceiverRecord> entries = mActions.get(action);
        if (entries == null) return false; // no receivers for that action
        ArrayList<ReceiverRecord> receivers = new ArrayList<ReceiverRecord>();
        for (ReceiverRecord receiver : entries) {
            if (receiver.broadcasting) continue;
            // match the intent
            int match = receiver.filter.match(action,
                intent.resolveTypeIfNeeded(mAppContext.getContentResolver()),
                intent.getScheme(), intent.getData(),
                intent.getCategories(), "LocalBroadcastManager");
            if (match >= 0) {
                receivers.add(receiver);
                receiver.broadcasting = true;
            }
        }
        final int size = receivers.size();
        if (size == 0) return false; // no receivers for this intent
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            receivers.get(i).broadcasting = false;
        }
        mPendingBroadcasts.add(new BroadcastRecord(intent, receivers));
        if (!mHandler.hasMessages(MSG_EXEC_PENDING_BROADCASTS)) {
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_EXEC_PENDING_BROADCASTS);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

where:

```
    mHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper()) {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MSG_EXEC_PENDING_BROADCASTS:
                    executePendingBroadcasts();
                    break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
```

I am not sure if there can be a race between the main thread and the thread `sendBroadcastSync()` is executing - so the `executePendingBroadcasts()` will run on the main thread. If not then `executePendingBroadcasts()` runs on the thread `sendBroadcastSync` is run and [directly calls](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.java#297) the onReceive of the receivers

One of these days I should look into why (in executePendingBroadcasts) `synchronized(mReceivers)` and not `synchronized(mPendingBroadcasts)`.

Answer (score 6):

I had been getting the same issue with the `sendBroadcastSync(Intent intent)` with the `LocalBroadcastManager`. When I had been trying to update the view from the `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` it threw the below exception:

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Eventually, I came to know that it might not run on the UI thread and hence resorted to using the simple code below:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            ....
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setProgressBar();
                }
            });
        }
```