# android broadcasts and wake locks synchronization

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I have a service A, which is started by WakefulBroadcastReciever from  AlarmManager.  Service A follows a standard pattern - performs a computation, then sends local broadcast  to inform the system about the results, then calls WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent().

Depending of the results of the computation,i.e. content of the local broadcast, other local services may need to perform some computation immediately. However, am I guaranteed that the other services will receive the local broadcast at all before the device goes back to sleep?

If not, I guess another solution would be to use explicit callbacks. 
Is there a standard pattern for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local Broadcast manager has a sync mode. Beware ! The `onReceive` runs in the thread it is called from - not the main (UI) thread.

Comment: Indeed, its sendBroadcastSync. Thanks.

Comment: @komark: do have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20820244/on-which-thread-does-onreceive-of-a-broacastreceiver-registered-with-localbroa